# How to avoid network (internet) connection to be interrupted in metro app when network connectivity switches from 4G to 3G or from 3G to 2G?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi i am developing an metro application , in which i am accessing the services to get some data from the services, in that moment if the network connectivity switches from 4G to 3G or from 3G to 2G the process gets interrupted and gets stops. how can i avoid this.

1)how can avoid network connectivity interruption when accessing services if it switchs between from 4G to 3G or from 3G to 2G ??

2)What are the various ways in which i can do it ?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the IP address of the device changing when switching connectivity? If it is the case, the interruption of open connections is unavoidable; a solution could be detecting the interruption and resuming the connection (using a protocol that supports resume).

Answer (score 1):

1. you can't avoid interruption if there is actually an interrupion
2. You could establish a network bridge to improve a bit your scenario http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-vista/create-a-network-bridge
   using this method, you can have an ip adress not directly related to your current connection. Network connectivity will be loosed during the switch, but the app should not be aware of it. Of course if you are downloading something during the switch, the socket will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use NetworkStatusChanged event and implement the right behavior that suits your application.  [Recommended app behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700376.aspx) are documented at msdn.